# Multithread core data merge error

Tags: core-data

The standard way of using multithread core-data is

```
[mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                          withObject:notification
                       waitUntilDone:YES];
```

However, the one have external managed object that save immediately after another. This creates errors. For example:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)    
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:YES];    
}

- (void) loadingIntoCoreData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [ctx setUndoManager:nil];
    [ctx setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [self persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:ctx];
    ...
    // Create many objects
    [ctx save:&error];
    [self doSomethingWithThisCtx:ctx];
}

- (void) doSomethingWithThisCtx:(NSManagedObjectContext *)ctx{
  // Form relationships with objects create in - (void) loadingIntoCoreData
  [ctx save:&error];
}
```

Then on the second [ctx save:&error] will throw an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.

How would one insert into core data and create relationships with the new objects on a separate thread? It works fine on the main thread but since it's done during `applicationDidLaunched`, then the UI get locked up.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't call the main thread context directly. Instead, you register the object that holds the main thread context for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` of the context on the background thread. Upon recent of the notification, call the main thread context's `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:` and  pass it the notification object. The main thread will then update itself.

This makes sure that the main thread is updated before it tries to use any of the objects added or deleted on the background thread.

Comment: sorry, perhaps it wasn't clear in my abbreviated code. I've put in the full code now. As you can see, I am registering the notification and calling the merge upon receiving the notification, perform the main thread context's update.

Comment: however, because of concurrency, while the main thread is merging changes, the background thread continues to run the `doSomethingWithThisCtx` and hence create conflict.

Comment: If you are making changes in both context simultaneously, you will need to register each context with the other for change notifications so they are both aware of what is going on. In general, you should attempt to avoid such situations whenever possible.